# como obtener hora actual correcta con php?

Tags: php

Estoy leyendo la hora actual con

`date("H:i:s");`

y sale adelantada una hora, busqué y le puse al html

`date_default_timezone_set('America/Caracas');`

pero al aplicarle eso sale atrasada media hora a la hora actual real, como puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 2):

Te pongo dos ejemplos uno para mi pa+is y uno para el tuyo y veas como se usa

Con lo siguiente te evitas de configuraciones complejas y que puedan ser innecesarias

Procura que el orden de declaración de sentencias siga a los ejemplos que te muestro

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');
echo date("H:i:s");
```

Ahora para el tuyo en Venezuela y en ambos funciona perfecto

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Caracas');
echo date("H:i:s");
```

Con la función de default_timezone_set() solo necesitas pasar en forma de cadena de texto el lugar y así funcionará

Comment: Gracias, la solucion fue aplicar ese date_default_timezone_set('America/Caracas');, y echo date("H:i:s"); pero resulta que se atrasaba media hora entonces vi por alli que tenia que hacer algo asi:$hora=date("H:i:s a ",time()+1800); y en mi local funcionó, ahora en el remoto no tenia que sumar esa media hora solo con las dos instrucciones que tu me proporcionaste

Comment: Si la puedes entonces marcar por favor

Comment: Pero utilizando date_default_timezone_set('America/Caracas'); no afecta si se abre en otros paises? quisiera que se pudiera utilizar en varios paises

Answer (score 1):

Puedes intentar en tu php.ini modificar las lineas y reinicias tu apache para que tome los nuevos valores.

```
    [Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone = America/Caracas
```